# Getting a 406 Not Acceptable from Typeform API only when using python-requests

Tags: python-requests, http-status-code-406, typeform

The Typeform "view form as JSON" (ex: https://api.typeform.com/forms/rGVAYs No  Authentiction Needed) API endpoint returns a `406 Not Acceptable` error when connecting via the python `requests`  library, but from no other client.

The request headers sent by python requests are the following:

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: python-requests/2.21.0
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason that is unknown to me, the Typeform "view form as JSON" API endpoint seems to reject requests coming from the python `requests` library (only?), sending an HTTP error `406 Not Acceptable`

The solution to this is to add a header specifying a different `User-Agent`, essentially spoofing the User Agent

```
import requests

header = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0",
}
resp = requests.get("https://api.typeform.com/forms/rGVAYs", headers=header)
print (resp.content)
```